# Increment column of cells by 1 if a condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a macro that will change columns C:5 to C:bottom of the sheet.

These cells should be incremented by 1 if the cell to the left (B:5 to end) is equal to the string 'TRUE'.

Here is what I have so far but the condition is not being met. I also don't know the best way to apply this to the whole column. Should I do a for loop?

Here is what I have so far

```
function increment() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var reocurring = spreadsheet.getRange("B5").getValue().toString();

  if (reocurring == 'TRUE')
  {
    var value = spreadsheet.getRange('C5').getValue();
    spreadsheet.getRange('C5').setValue(value + 1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your `if` statement condition isn't being met. This is because `getValue()` returns values *with* their associated type. Your "TRUE" value is being recognized as a boolean, not string like your `if` statement is looking for. You are using `toString()` but this changes the value to 'true' rather than 'TRUE', so your `if` statement condition still is not met.

---

#### Solution:

There are a few ways around this:

1. Change your `if` statement to look for a boolean:

   ```
   if (reocurring === true)
   ```
2. Force the value to string and upper case to make sure your condition is met:

   ```
   var reocurring = spreadsheet.getRange("B5").getValue().toString().toUpperCase();
   ```
3. Use `getDisplayValue()` to return a string from the beginning:

   ```
   var reocurring = spreadsheet.getRange("B5").getDisplayValue();
   ```

---

#### Looping through the sheet:

Since this could be quite a long-running script if you're running it for a large data set, it's best to work with arrays here. I've tried to comment the code so it's a little easier to understand but if you have any questions please let me know.

```
function increment() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //get array values in columns B and C starting from row 5
  var array = spreadsheet.getRange(5, 2, spreadsheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  //loop through array
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][0] === true) {
      //increment value in row C by 1
      array[i][1] = array[i][1] + 1;
    }
  }
  //set new incremented values
  spreadsheet.getRange(5, 2, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

---

#### References:

- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [JavaScript Data Types](https://javascript.info/types)

Comment: Wow you are a spreadsheet master, thankyou so much for this :)