# My if statement doesn't seem to output anything

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using an if statement on the condition if a cell has a value of 'TRUE', if it does I want another cell to have the value given in the statement

I'm using this to work out which boxes have been checked. So if one box is checked it shows 'TRUE', then I want the other cell to show the action that the box has checked for. e.g if the purchasing box is ticked, I want the other cell to show 'Purchased'.

```
var submit_type_corrective = submit_sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
  var submit_type_Opportunity = submit_sheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
  var submit_type_Preventative =submit_sheet.getRange('E7').getValue();
  var type_submitted = log_sheet.getRange(lastRow_log+1,3);


  if (submit_type_corrective == 'TRUE'){
    type_submitted.setValue('Corrective');
  }


else if (submit_type_Opportunity == 'TRUE'){type_submitted.setValue('Opportunity')}
           else {type_submitted.setValue('Preventative')
    }
```

I want the cell to show Corrective, but it displays with nothing even though the box is checked

Comment: That's definied in earlier code. It's just the last row of another sheet, that seems to be working for all the other submitted variables. It does set the values correctly for all the other variables

Comment: Just tried that now, it seems to still not change anything

Comment: Try using `Logger.log(submit_type_corrective);` and checking the output in the log, what does it return?

Comment: Just put it after you define the variable then run the script and check the log to find the output.

Comment: It says the value is true, even though in google sheets it is TRUE

Comment: OK, try changing your `if` statement to `if (submit_type_corrective == true){` instead.

Comment: That's worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: I've explained how this is working and how to fix it in another question already. Take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305047/increment-column-of-cells-by-1-if-a-condition-is-met/57305885#57305885) if you want to read in more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment column of cells by 1 if a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305047/increment-column-of-cells-by-1-if-a-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1):

[`Range.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) returns a value as its corresponding type (e.g., number, boolean, date, or string).

The default underlying type of of checkbox cells in Google Sheets is **boolean**, not string.

Try changing:

```
  if (submit_type_corrective == 'TRUE') {
```

to

```
  if (submit_type_corrective == true) {
```

or simply

```
  if (submit_type_corrective) {
```

And similarly, you'll have to update:

```
  if (submit_type_Opportunity == 'TRUE') {
```

to

```
  if (submit_type_Opportunity == true) {
```

or

```
  if (submit_type_Opportunity) {
```

---

**Tip:** You can inspect the type of values in Google Apps Script by doing

```
Logger.log(typeof submit_type_corrective);
```

[image]